# repo tool deletes obsolete paths in checkout

Tags: repo

If your repository has a few paths that are synced by the repo tool using a manifest-file/group/branch & you run the repo commands (init->sync->checkout) again in the same repository but with some other manifest-file/group/branch having a different set of project paths then the current execution of the repo command will remove/delete the unnecessary project paths.

At least, what I expected from the repo tool was that the project paths which were not relevant to the current execution to be kept as is.

But, instead, you'll see a sequence of log lines saying the obsolete paths have been **deleted** as they were not necessary.

```
Deleting obsolete path /path/to/other/project1
Deleting obsolete path /path/to/other/project2
Deleting obsolete path /path/to/other/project3
Deleting obsolete path /path/to/other/project4
```

Repo tool has this by design.

I looked at multiple problems over the internet for solutions but couldn't find any.
Finally, I could design my own ***WAR***.

Comment: Note, this happens specifically for the last execution's retained .repo/project-list file

Comment: If removed, next iteration will auto-generate it with expected list of projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internally, the repo tool decides which paths to keep & which to delete in 2 ways.

- If the paths to be deleted has some changes then it ignores deleting them.
- By comparing the ***project.list*** file in the **.repo** folder & only keeps the ones listed in it.

Method 1 wasn't much useful for me as before the checkout I happen to reset the entire working tree. 
On the other hand, Method 2 was what I needed. 

**WAR**
Update the project.list file in .repo folder of the repository to remove the paths that you think the repo tool should not delete.
Let's say I don't want repo tool to mess up my path "/path/to/other/project3" then I would remove this line from project.list file.